# IE: window.open returning null

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

on a click event, I am running this code:

```
win = window.open(a.href);
i = setInterval(function () {
    if (win.closed) {
        /* do things */
    }
}, 250);
```

this works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE (9) it says that win is undefined or null. How can I work around this?

EDIT: The window IS opened correctly in IE, it's just that a reference to it is not saved in win like it is in Firefox/Chrome.

Comment: it's an openid url (depends on which the user clicked)

Comment: but where/how is it set/sent? can you add it please?

Comment: well see, it does actually open the window to the correct location. The actual url is one local to my site that then redirects to the google/yahoo/whatever openid provider url. it starts with something like http://mysite.com/openid?url=http://openidproviderurl (all properly encoded as needed of course)

Comment: i'm using mootools, the a reference is from something like this: $$('a.openid_login').each(function (a) { a.addEvent('click', function (event) { /* the code above */ }});

Comment: Works properly in my IE 9, look at http://jsfiddle.net/3EPRT/7/.

Answer (score 2):

Add name to the window:

```
win = window.open(a.href, "myWin");
```

Comment: When you add `alert(a.href);` what do you see?

Comment: I see the URL that's I'm opening. The window opens correctly.

Comment: Please post more code, maybe it will help us see what cause this problem then.